# How to set the date to 0 in Google Forms using Google script

Tags: javascript, forms, date, initialization

I'm trying to design an option questionnaire.  The person makes choices that lead to different pages with different options.  When the respondent has made their choice, I ask them for a desired date.

The data is sent to Google Sheets for storage and processing by another script.

My problem is that when the questionnaire is validated, the dates of all questionnaire options are automatically filled in on the date of completion.

How can I make the dates 0 if they are not filled in?

Comment: How do you set the default date now?

Comment: Its hard to see whats wrong without any code, it could be how the validation is done.

Comment: What do you mean "set the date to 0"? `new Date(0)` creates a date for 1970-01-01.

Comment: @RobG I found it, the problem is that i made my google forms but uses it with AppSheet... and AppSheet sets a init value for the requested date at TODAY() while i didn't ask for it... So i only need to delete the argument....

Comment: @Vince : Thanks too,so sorry, I don't know to add screenshots...

Comment: @LaurentRavelOrthomedic no problem, please add and answer to your question and mark it is solved.

Comment: @Vince so sorry, I'm newbie, how do I do "solved" status ?

Comment: Post an answer to you own question, then you can mark it as solved